# Cross reference with page number

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

In LaTeX, there is the possibility of using `\vref{...}` for a reference, which creates a text like *figure 12 on page 15*. It has the benefit that it is intelligent enough to do a simple distinction:

**Am I at page 15?**
Write *figure 12*.

**Am I at page 14?** 
Write *figure 12 on the facing page*.

**Am I at page 16?**
Write *figure 12 on the previous page*.

(If it was on page 16 and we are at page 15, write *figure 12 on the next page*.)

**Am I somewhere else?**
Write *figure 12 on page 15*.

When working with Winword, I haven't found anything like that yet. All I can do is to insert a reference to the figure and another one to its page number.

Is there any way to achieve that `\vref`-y style of a cross reference in Word?

Comment: no you can't do that in Word using cross references.

Comment: That was *not* the answer I was hoping for, but thanks nonetheless. :-)

Comment: You can do it with nested IF fields though - perhaps you could insert the Figure xref in usual way and then use a macro to convert that to the nested IF fields which are updated by the macro to insert the selected Figure field reference and its associated pageref field value.